# Searching JSON, Returning String within the JSON Structure

Tags: python, json

I have a set of JSON data that looks simular to this:

```
{"executions": [
{
  "id": 17,
  "orderId": 16,
  "executionStatus": "1",
  "cycleId": 5,
  "projectId": 15006,
  "issueId": 133038,
  "issueKey": "QTCMP-8",
  "label": "",
  "component": "",
  "projectKey": "QTCMP",
  "executionDefectCount": 0,
  "stepDefectCount": 0,
  "totalDefectCount": 0
},
{
  "id": 14,
  "orderId": 14,
  "executionStatus": "1",
  "cycleId": 5,
  "projectId": 15006,
  "issueId": 133042,
  "issueKey": "QTCMP-10",
  "label": "",
  "component": "",
  "projectKey": "QTCMP",
  "executionDefectCount": 0,
  "stepDefectCount": 0,
  "totalDefectCount": 0
    }
  ],
  "currentlySelectedExecutionId": "",
  "recordsCount": 4
}
```

I have taken this and parsed it with Python as below:

```
import json
import pprint

with open('file.json') as dataFile:
    data = json.load(dataFile)
```

With this I am able to find sets of data like executions by doing data["executions"] etc.. What I need to be able to do is search for the string "QTCMP-8" within the structure, and then when I find that specific string, find the "id" that is associated with that string. So in the case of QTCMP-8 it would be id 17; for QTCMP-10 it would be 14.

Is this possible? Do I need to convert the data first? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you need to check the value corresponding to `issueKey` key or `projectKey`

Comment: Added an answer assuming you need `issueKey` based on the example you provided above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in computational order of O(1), at least with what it is like now. The following is a solution with O(n) complexity for each search.

```
id = None
for dic in executions:
    if dic['issueKey'] == query:
        id = dic['id']
        break
```

Doing this in O(1), need a pre-processing of O(n), in which you categorize executions by their **issueKey**, and save inside it whatever information you want.

```
# Preprocessing of O(n)
mapping = dict()
for dic in executions:
    mapping[dic['issueKey']] = {
        'id':  dic['id'],
        'whatever': 'whateverel'
    }

# Now you can query in O(1)

return dic[query]['id']
```

You might also want to consider working with [MongoDB](http://mongodb.com/) or likes of it, if you're doing heavy json querying.

Comment: Using `dict()` is generally not good practice - using `{}` which declares an empty `dict` is much better. (it doesn't require a name lookup, it can be peephole optimised and that name could have been shadowed by another poorly named function or variable etc..).

Comment: You could also write the later example as a dict-comp: `mapping = {d['issueKey']: d for d in executions['executions']}`

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for pointing out the better practice ! I'll keep that in mind. About the comprehension though, I guess it's better to provide cleaner syntax, specially in cases where the OP seems not much accustomed to python.

Comment: @JonClements Can you provide me with some resource on why peephole optimization works better for *{}* than *dict* ? I don't seem to understand why would it be the case

Comment: @Jon Clements why is `dict()` not good practice? What about with args: `dict( somekey=someval, anotherkey=otherval,...)`

Comment: @nigel222 the builtin `dict` is fine like that... just try a simple test of `dict = int` then try to use it in a scope that has a shadowed `dict` available.

Answer (score 0):

A simple iteration with a condition will do the job:

```
for execution in data['executions']:
    if "QTCMP" in execution['issueKey']:
        print(execution["id"])

# -> 17
# -> 14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of all ids as:

```
>>> [item['id'] for item in my_json['executions'] if item['issueKey'].startswith('QTCMP')]
[17, 14]
```

where `my_json` is the variable storing your JSON structure

**Note:** I am using `item['issueKey'].startswith('QTCMP')` instead of `'QTCMP' in item['issueKey']` as you need id of items starting with `QTCMP`. For example, if the value is `XXXQTCMP`, it's id should not present with the result (but it will result as `True` on using `in` statement)